# Numpy with python 3.0

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x

NumPy installer can't find python path in the registry.

> Cannot install Python version 2.6 required, which was not found in the
>   registry.

Is there a numpy build which can be used with python 3.0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there is not [yet] a version of numpy that has been ported to Python 3.

the last update I heard from the people on the project was this:
http://blog.jarrodmillman.com/2009/01/when-will-numpy-and-scipy-migrate-to.html

for now, if you need Numpy, you are stuck with Python 2.x

Comment: Warren, that's great news.  got a link?

Comment: See my answer which has a link.

Answer (score 46):

Guido van Rossum (creator of Python) says he is [keen to see NumPy work in Python 3.x](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/11/python-in-scientific-world.html), because it would enable many dependent libraries to move to 3.x.

**Update 2010-08-05:** [NumPy version 1.5 supports Python 3.x, and SciPy will soon.](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg26524.html) NumPy 1.5 beta is [available for download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/) now.

**Update 2012-05-31:** [SciPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/) [0.10.0 added support for Python 3.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.10.0/) in November 2011.

Comment: great links.  especially see: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2010-February/048616.html

Answer (score 7):

The current development verson of Numpy is compatible with Python 3 -- you can get it from Numpy's SVN and build it yourself. It will probably be released later this year (probably in the summer) as Numpy 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

Scipy now also supports Python 3 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.10.0/).