# Where on Earth is the numpy download for python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Where on Earth is the download for numpy for python 3.x? I realize there is already a question like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231842/numpy-with-python-3-0), but that was 3 years ago and all the links are outdated or dead. I've found tons of downloads saying they are for python 2.7 like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/), but none for python 3. Am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: Look a bit closer at that SourceForge link. There are installers for 2.7, 3.1, 3.2 and 3.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're in the correct place - http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.7.2/ - in the same directory is a link to numpy-1.7.2-win32-superpack-python3.3.exe/download

*NumPy 1.7.2 Release Notes ************************* This is a bugfix only release in the 1.7.x series. It supports Python 2.4 - 2.7 and 3.1 - 3.3 and is the last series that supports Python 2.4 - 2.5.*

Or you can get pre-compiled windows binaries here - http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/ has several Python 3 binaries (for recent versions). So does http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy. Running `easy_install numpy` or `pip install numpy` should also work. Downloading the source and running its `setup.py` with any supported Python version should work as well.

Comment: You're kidding about using setup.py on Windows right? Building NumPy is quite involved, especially on Windows where it's uncommon for users to have a C compiler, let alone a Fortran compiler.

Comment: @eryksun On windows, it's indeed rather involved. But nobody said anything about Windows in particular, and on other operating systems it appears to work rather well. Note that the same problems apply to `easy_install` and `pip` (there aren't any wheels, and won't be until the ABI compatibility problems are fixed).

Comment: I assumed the OP is looking for windows binaries as the link they provided was to the windows installer for 2.7. What do you mean by wheels and the ABI compatibility problem?

Comment: @user2981639 [Wheels](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/) have an ABI tag to prevent installing the wrong binaries. However, it's not powerful enough to prevent some ABI incompatibilites numpy can run into (e.g. it doesn't mention SSE, so you might wind up installing an SSE2-only binary on an old CPU without SSE2 support).